# How is one sentence of unsubstantiated opinion the best answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality, not-an-answer

I recently asked a question and received [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/829306/41023):

> No, hard drives are in sealed enclosures and these images are marketing shots to give you an idea of the engineering inside.

That's it. One sentence of ***opinion*** with no supporting facts whatsoever.

There are, currently, 4 other answers and they all provide ***evidence***, and/or details to back up their claims<sup>1</sup>. Yet this answer has 4 times as many votes as any other answer!!!

- Does evidence count for so little on SuperUser? How can this be the best answer when, by rights, it should be converted to a comment?
- Is there vote fraud afoot?
- Should I bow to public opinion and switch the accepted answer?

---

<sup>1</sup> A 6th answer was deleted.

Comment: Certainly a better answer than *"I have no idea why anyone would show an open drive; it just seems dumb."*

Comment: @slhck, true.  But he fixed that with some prompting.

Comment: Well, the OP did not fix it. It was your (radical) edit that removed this part and made the answer factual. Not saying that this is the wrong approach (especially if the OP accepts your edit), but if it weren't for this edit I would have deleted the post that you accepted.

Comment: This is the very reason I push for people to post factual answers not opinion based response and normally downvote them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Depends on the question, but upvotes to an extent is a popularity contest.
2. Unlikely
3. No, pick what you consider to be the best answer.

That said, that's a pretty odd question, and I'm waffling on whether it passes the 'minimal research' test.

Comment: Well, I did check 3 stores and tried many Google searches. But the terms (hard drive, case, exposed, open, cover, etc.) are so overloaded that it's difficult.  It also wouldn't be the first time that what I had known to be a hard-fast rule of tech was superseded.  Ironically, a comment led to me getting the answer I needed and [Cornstalk's comment](http://superuser.com/questions/829304/do-hard-drives-really-have-open-cases-now/829306#comment-1088932) was better than any of the answers.

Answer (score -4):

Given that the average person is pretty dumb, and half the people in the world are dumber than them, any system that allows the uneducated and unintelligent to vote will likely result in poor results.

Voting on this site requires a low number of points and is unmoderated.  Voting requires no wisdom, knowledge, compassion, or intelligence.

On a larger scale, just look at the type of people who routinely win political elections to see what happens when these people are allowed to vote.  Of course, not allowing them to vote has its issues as well...